# Which high level interface to use instead of Network for sending and haskell `Strings`

Tags: string, haskell, networking

The first line of documentation of the [`Network`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network-2.6.3.2/docs/Network.html) module reads:

> This module is kept for backwards-compatibility. New users are encouraged to use Network.Socket instead.

The `Network` library has functions that allow to send and receive `Strings` in a convenient manner, for instance:

```
  h <- connectTo "localhost" (PortNumber 9090)
  -- ...
  line <- hGetLine h
```

Without using this library (and using `Network.Socket` instead), the code above will become something like:

```
addrinfos <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just "") (Just "9090")
let serveraddr = head addrinfos
sock <- socket (addrFamily serveraddr) Stream defaultProtocol
connect sock (addrAddress serveraddr)
-- ...
msg <- recv sock Size
-- What `Size` should be? The line above should be probably repeated until all the data is received.
```

Which is is quite low level, and requires coding/decoding a `String`'s. So my question is, if all I want to do is to send and receive strings (with some encoding) over a socket what are the alternatives for accomplishing this task, provided that `Network` is not an option?

**EDIT**: although pipes are conduits are good options, the project I'm working on makes heavy use of these `Network` functions, so I ended up developing a [library](https://github.com/capitanbatata/text-via-sockets) for sending and receiving `Text` using similar functions as in the `Network` library.

Comment: Can't you use `socketToHandle` to convert a socket into a `Handle` and use `hGetLine` on that?

Comment: I would probably use a streaming library for handling decoding and line splitting. `pipes` + `pipes-bytestring` + `pipes-text` for example, or the counduit equivalents http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.2.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Text.html#v:lines

Comment: Using `socketToHandle` would solve part of the problem, but that will expose me to [this bug] (https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14503), which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Well, yeah, then probably either conduit-extra with Data.Conduit.Network or pipes-network is your best bet. Former seems fair bit more feature-complete.